# How to add members to a PSObject in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, mocking, moles

I'm using Microsoft Moles to mock a method.

This method call another method that invokes a PowerShell script and returns

> Collection`<PSObject>`

So I want to mock it to return a custom PSObject.
It will have two properties, ID and Name.

But when I try to use

```
PSObject obj = new PSObject();
obj.Members.Add(new PSMemberInfo(
```

I found the constructor is protected.

How can I add properties?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PSMemberInfo` is a abstract class, so you cannot make an instance directly, but choose its subclass

in the page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pspropertyinfo(v=vs.85).aspx you can find below:

```
System.Object 
   System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo
    System.Management.Automation.PSPropertyInfo
       System.Management.Automation.PSAliasProperty
       System.Management.Automation.PSCodeProperty
       System.Management.Automation.PSNoteProperty
       System.Management.Automation.PSProperty
       System.Management.Automation.PSScriptProperty
```

Choose your class, and init it.

Comment: Try PSNoteProperty, that is what I use in my mocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different member type in place of PSNoteProperty

```
PSObject individualPsObject = new PSObject();
individualPsObject.Members.Add(new PSNoteProperty("Name", "Value"));
```